# In English, can the use of a word change from formal to informal, or vice versa, while the meaning of the word remains the same?

Tags: historical-linguistics, language-change, formality

*Note: I have zero background in linguistics, so I do not know if my question is valid, and I am probably not going to use proper terminology. Thank you for reading. Here goes.*

**Can the use of a word change from formal to informal, or vice versa, while the meaning of the word remains the same?**

For example, take the word "sweet", as in:

> "The exam has been cancelled? Sweet!"
> "I just downloaded a sweet app."
> "He's got a sweet jump shot."

Here, the meaning of "sweet" is something like: *pleasing to the mind or feelings; gratifying* ([thefreedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sweet)). This use of "sweet" is decidedly *informal*.

But I just read that the use of "[the sweet science](https://shortboxing.com/why-is-boxing-called-the-sweet-science/)", to refer to the sport of boxing, dates back to 1813. It seems that in this context "sweet" also meant *pleasing to the mind or feelings; gratifying*. What about the register (in 1813): was it formal, or informal?

More generally, can the formality of a word change over time, while its meaning remains the same?

Comment: The sense you quote (from senses 3a and 3b under the second _sweet_ entry in the TFD link) is not particularly informal – it’s quite neutral. The uses in your blockquote relate rather to sense 12, which _is_ informal. Being an avid avoider of boxing, I’d never heard it referred to as the ‘sweet science’, and the name doesn’t really make sense to me. All the sites I can find that supposedly explain it only describe why it’s called a science, although none of the meanings of _sweet_ really makes sense either.

Comment: "formal" and "informal" aren't really very well defined. At best they refer to different [registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)). Which means of course the use of a word can change between "formal" and "informal" - we all constantly adjust how we speak blurring the lines between registers, often even in the middle of a single sentence!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Despite which definition in the TFD link is labelled as slang, I feel that "pleasing to the mind or senses" is a slightly better description than "remarkable; oustanding", of the meaning of "sweet" as used in the blockquote (so I guess my providing the reference may be confusing). As far as boxing, my understanding is that, boxing is not just punching someone; there are elegant principles and a well-developed body of knowledge involved, thus making the sport pleasing to the intellect.

Comment: @Dan ‘Outstanding’ here should be understood as ‘fantastic, amazing’, I think (rather than just ‘noteworthy’), which matches the quotes better. ‘Pleasing to the mind/senses’ doesn’t match the meaning I associate with _sweet_ in the examples you give – it just means ‘awesome’.